# about personal center viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to achieve such effect，but I'm searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

[image: Expected]

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in a  more specific way?

Comment: @Chakery you can google it using "parallax scrolling ios" so you will get a option as you like

Comment: What you want looks like the default behavior of an `UICollectionVIew` with `bounces = true`

Comment: Details on the problem:
`UITableView` has a background image, and `tableViewHeaderView` is transparent, but `TableView` is not transparent.
When the drop-down can see the background image, and can't see the background when pulled.

Answer (score 0):

You could put header view inside tableHeaderView like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Background imageView put under tableView.

Last thing is top status bar background rectangle,
I recommend to use this library https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar

Comment: I wanna fixed background image. and `tableHeaderView` is transparent, but `tableview` is not transparent.